# How to exclude static resources from requestmapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm trying to exclude static resources from @RequestMapping path to avoid redundant calls to methods.

I tried to simply check the url and if its a resource to do nothing but the interceptor didn't find the resource after and it ran the methods anyway because they are annotated with @ModelAttribute.

GlobalController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    public static int k;

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @ModelAttribute("unread")
    public int unread(Principal principal) {

        int unread = 0;

        k++;
        System.err.println("Inside unread " + k);

        if (principal != null) {
            User user = usersService.getWithUser(principal.getName(), "notifications");
            for (Notification n : user.getNotifications())
                if (!n.isRead())
                    unread++;
        }

        return unread;
    }
}
```

The resources handler

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

The expected result should exclude all urls that contain "static", but now it doesn't and unread() is being called for every image and script in my jsp pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with Spring only, it's possible but a bit messy:

1. You'll either need to use a [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping) for which you
   can explicitly specify URL patterns which should be mapped to
   controllers OR extend it to support "ignore" URLs like "css/**".
2. You'll need to write your own [HttpRequestHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestHandler.html) implementation that
   would basically consist of
   "getServletContext().getRequestDsipatcher().include()" call to
   return the requested resource as is.
3. You'll have to register that handler as defaultHandler for the above
   SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.

Once all that is done, all requests that can't be mapped to your controllers will be forwarded to your `HttpRequestHandler` and served "as is".

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
public class DefaultView extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringMVCViewInspection")
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/files/**").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }
}
```

[screenshot of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm5GE.png)